# "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class FacebookApiException

Tags: facebook, class

I have installed the instabuilder plug in and somehow the SEO Facebook C. plugin is conflicting with it.

Only when the `SEO Facebook C.` plugin is active accessing this page: http://www.jmuller777.com/blog/?mode=facebook_tab gives me the fallowing error:

> "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class FacebookApiException in
>   /home/denrrou/public_html/jmuller777.com/blog/wp-content/plugins/InstaBuilder/inc/facebook/base_facebook.php
>   on line 107"

I have read that it should be a class issue, but i cant figure out where to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Redeclare can mean, that you include the class file twice for example. Be sure that you use `include_once(...)`

Or you have 2 plugins that use the same class. You can Search for "FacebookApiException" in your plugin code.

greetings

Comment: Can i delete that in one of the two plugins without compromising its functionality?

Comment: A found the "FacebookApiException" in base_facebook.php

Comment: A found the "FacebookApiException" in base_facebook.php within the SEO facebook comments, it should be interfering with the instabuilder plugin. Please, what can i do to solve this?

Comment: maybe you have to look into the code files of the plugins and rename one of the classes in one of the plugins OR you look for the includes and change the call to the same file and use include_once instead of include. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php I dont know the plugins so i can only give you some generally tips.

Comment: want to be a freelancer on this job?

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. Just deactivate the plugins that might conflict, activate the one that givs the error and then activate the ones you deactivated earlier.